# How to extract every n by n matrix in an m by m matrix

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to retrieve 225, 30 by 30 matrices from one matrix which is 450 by 450

using slicing I'm able to get one 30 by 30 matrix but I'm not sure how to iterate through and get the rest, is there anyway to do this?

```
x = 30
extract = []
extract1 = []

while ( x < 450 ):
    extract1 = test1[x:, x:]
    x += 30
    extract.append(extract1)
```

Comment: There are many ways to extract 30x30 matrices from your big matrix, please clarify which ones you want extracted and what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I want all 225 of them, however with the code above as it iterates the matrix becomes 60 by 60 and so on. my code only works for extracting the first 30 by 30 matrix

Comment: *Why"do you want to do this? Some of the solutions below answer the question correctly, but there are more efficient ways, especially if afterwards you're going to compute the mean or the sum over each new 30x30 quadrant. Also, this question was asked a few days ago, by an author that removed his own question. If that's you, then don't doublepost.

Comment: once the data provide in "test1" is extracted and reshaped in a suitable way I am then applying it to a provided function which will classify the data. And no that wasn't me, would have refered to the question had it not been deleted

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy's strided views:

```
import numpy as np

def make_windows(x, ws):
    m,n = x.shape
    s,t = ws
    shape = (m/s, n/t) + ws
    strides = (s * x.strides[0], t * x.strides[1]) + x.strides
    windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    return windows.reshape(-1, s, t)
```

Let's try it out on some data:

```
>>> data = np.arange(450*450).reshape(450,450)
>>> windows = make_windows(data, (30,30))
>>> windows.shape
(225, 30, 30)
>>> windows
array([[[     0,      1,      2, ...,     27,     28,     29],
        [   450,    451,    452, ...,    477,    478,    479],
        [   900,    901,    902, ...,    927,    928,    929],
        ..., 
        [ 12150,  12151,  12152, ...,  12177,  12178,  12179],
        [ 12600,  12601,  12602, ...,  12627,  12628,  12629],
        [ 13050,  13051,  13052, ...,  13077,  13078,  13079]],

       [[    30,     31,     32, ...,     57,     58,     59],
        [   480,    481,    482, ...,    507,    508,    509],
        [   930,    931,    932, ...,    957,    958,    959],
        ..., 
        [ 12180,  12181,  12182, ...,  12207,  12208,  12209],
        [ 12630,  12631,  12632, ...,  12657,  12658,  12659],
        [ 13080,  13081,  13082, ...,  13107,  13108,  13109]],

        ...,
```

Comment: This is the approach I'd go for as well, followed up by an `einsum` or such. Very memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives you the desired output, though I am sure there is a more elegant way to do it.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
extracts = []
x = 2

for i in xrange(x):
    for j in xrange(x):
        extracts.append(a[i*x :x + i*x, j*x : x + j*x])
```